# trying to get circle left and paragraph message right

Tags: html, css

My goal is to get the circle div positioned left along with paragraph
message positioned right in div box.

ive tried using float right and float left in each class but circle
ends up out of document. If someone could show and tell me where i am
going wrong. I have also supplied a picture of what i am trying to
duplicate.

[image: trying to achieve]

```css
.container {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.grid-container-our-teachers {
  width: auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px 10px;
  font-family: theboldfont;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0px;
}

.grid-item-our-teachers {
  background-color: #19252A;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border-image-width: 100%;
  border: none;
  padding: 1em 2em 1.2em 2em;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: left;
  height: auto;
}

.grid-item-our-teachers p {
  font-size: 12.5px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  margin: 10px 0;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.circle-our-teachers {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 80px;
  background: white;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border: 5px solid black;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="grid-container-our-teachers">
    <div class="grid-item-our-teachers" style="color: black; background: white;">
      <h1>Our Teachers</h1>
      <p>At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati </p>


    </div>
    <div class="grid-item-workshops" style="background-image: url(img/STARS%2024.jpg)"></div>
    <div class="grid-item-our-teachers">

      <div class="circle-our-teachers">
      </div>
      <div class="ot-message">
        <p>Blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item-workshops">
      <div class="circle-our-teachers">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item-workshops"></div>
    <div class="grid-item-workshops"></div>


  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: your HTMl hardly reflects your screen shot, try to break your design into areas/ contents , then use for each areas and contents the tag that reflects best what it is wrapping. CSS will be be much easier to set and your html will be easiky redable

Answer (score 0):

Try to use flexbox.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox

You can set to container

```
display: flex;
flex-flow: row nowrap;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to restructure your code, make two blocks for each section, provide float: left property.

Please find below code snippet:

```css
section {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  color: white;
}

div {
  width: 50%;
  height: 150px;
}

.left {
  float: left;
  background: pink;
}
.second {
  background: blue;
}

.right {
  float: right;
  background: cyan;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="left">1</div>
  <div class="left second">2</div>
  </section>
  <section>
  <div class="left">3</div>
  <div class="left second">4</div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

From my comment:

> your HTMl hardly reflects your screen shot, try to break your design into areas/ contents , then use for each areas and contents the tag that reflects best what it is wrapping. CSS will be be much easier to set and your html will be easily readable

Here is a possiblity using grid with a coherent HTML structure that makes css easier and often more efficient:

```css
.container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: auto;
  background: rgb(28, 36, 39);
}

[class^="grid"] {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-auto-flow: row dense;
}

article[class^="grid"] {
  grid-template-columns: minmax(150px,3fr) 5fr;
  border: solid;
  color: white;
  padding:0.25em;
}

article:nth-child(3n) {/* to swap color titles rules from odd columns to even columns */
  grid-column: 2
}

article:before {
  content: '';
  width: 80%;
  padding-top: 80%;
  background: url(https://placeimg.com/200/200/people) white;
  border-radius: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}

article h1 {
  color: rgb(65, 152, 170)
}

article:nth-child(odd) h1 {
  color: rgb(160, 62, 112)
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <section class="grid-container-our-teachers">
    <article class="grid-item-our-teachers">

      <div>
        <h1>Our Teachers</h1>
        <p>At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati </p>
      </div>

    </article>
    <article class="grid-item-our-teachers">

      <div>
        <h1>Our Teachers</h1>
        <p>At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati </p>
      </div>

    </article>
    <article class="grid-item-our-teachers">

      <div>
        <h1>Our Teachers</h1>
        <p>At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati </p>
      </div>

    </article>
    <article class="grid-item-our-teachers">

      <div>
        <h1>Our Teachers</h1>
        <p>At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati </p>
      </div>

    </article>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks ive been trying to undersstand why you used the format i.e. article[class^="grid"] i am only familiar with .class #id

Comment: @freshcoder i used it to select any class that starts with grid to avoid typing the 2 long class we have here . see : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors it selects : `.grid-container-our-teachers`& `grid-container-our-teachers` but will also select any other class starting with `grid`